# Classical Architecture to Kafka, how do you realize the following?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

we are trying to move away from our classical architecture J2EE application server/Relational database to Kafka. I have an use case that I am not sure how exactly to proceed....

Our application exports with a Scheduler from Relation Database, in the future, we are planning to not to place information at all at Relational Database but to realise export directly from the information at Kafka Topic(s).

What I am not sure will be best solution would be, is to configure consumer that polls the topic(s) with the same schedule as the scheduler and export things.

Or to create KafkaStream at schedule triggering point to collect this information from a Kafka Stream?

What do you think?

Comment: I don't think that it would be a good idea to use Kafka as permanent storage. Kafka is not an alternative to classical relational databases.

Comment: @Giogios I think NewYork Times disagrees with that statement - you can find documentation that says they stored all news articles in Kafka

Comment: Regarding the question, though. If you keep the RDBMS, then enable CDC on its logs, then you can push all database events to Kafka. There doesn't have to be a "lift and shift" design

Comment: @Giogios One of the reason we decided to go from Relational Database to Kafka while we discerned that we had data retency of 3 days. The things we save to the relational database we don't need it more then 3 days.

Comment: It's okay to store data in Kafka - https://www.confluent.io/blog/okay-store-data-apache-kafka/. Treat it as a system of record, this pattern is growing in use.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you want to adopt is technically feasible, few possible solutions:

1) Continuous running Kafka-Consumer with `Duration=<export schedule time>`

2) Cron triggered kafka-streaming-consumer with batch-duration same as schedule. Do offset commit to Kafka.

3) Cron triggered Kafka-consumer programmatically handle offsets and pull records based on offsets as per your schedule.

**Important considerations:**

1. Increase retention.ms to much more than your schedule batch job time.
2. Increase disk space to accommodate data volume spike since you are going to hold data for longer duration.

**Risks & Issues:**

- Weekend retention could be missed.
- Another application if by mistake uses same group.id can mislead offsets.
- No aggregation/math function can be applied before retrieval.
- Your application can not filter/extract records based on any parameter.
- Unless offsets are managed externally, application can not re-read records.
- Records will not be formatted i.e. mostly Json strings or maybe some other formats.

Comment: With the default retention of a week, I doubt much Cron jobs are longer than that. Or at least monthly ones should be processing some other daily roll up

Comment: I think all your proposed solution are about using directly a consumer at the topic but for many of the reason you mentioned above would not make more sense then create KafkaStream and pull the information I need with a KTable...

Comment: @posthumecaver sure, it's upto you to see how you want to utilize the data. Since you are replacing DB with kafka, I assume you will need atleast some of the DB's capabilities i.e. data retention, multiple times read, multi client read/fetch etc, just think through before committing to a solution.